# Django-crontab is not working on in ec2 ubuntu virtual environment

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, cron

i use django-crontab library in mac m1 bigsur

```
# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django_crontab'
]

CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/5 * * * *', 'diagnoses.croncode.ChangeRegisterView')
]

# croncode.py

def ChangeRegisterView():
```

and i used `python manage.py crontab add`

It was installed in a virtual environment.
and It works well in a local environment.

however it's not working at ec2!!
The virtual environment anaconda python=3.8.11 version is installed and used by aws ec2.

like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ubuntu/safe-back/safe-back/safehomes/safehomes/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 224, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_crontab'
```

i want to two things.

1. I want to do a cronlog path in ec2 Ubuntu environment.
2. I want to turn django-crontab in ec2.

help bros!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the step to add cronjob in django using django-crontab (Mac, Linux)

1. Install the package

   pip3 install django-crontab

If that gives and issue then perform uninstallation command or force install by

```
python3 -m pip install django-crontab
```

2. add 'django_crontab' in your **INSTALLED_APPS**
3. create new crons.py file in your app named
4. add your cronjob method in crons.py, for example
5. add following configuration in your settings.py file

   CRON JOB SETTINGS

   ```
    CRONJOBS = [
        ('*/1 * * * *', 'your_app_name.crons.your_cronjob_method'),
    ]
   ```

Comment: I found a problem. The ec2 cron was looking at the base, not the conda I activated.